# Solving equation with integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the solution of this integration:

$$\int_o^v{vdv\over g-kv/ m}=\int_o^h dy$$

I have tried and my solution goes like this
$${m\over k} ln {vdv\over g-kv/ m}=y$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change of variables $$u = g - kv/m$$ should help you here :). Also your final solution is wrong should be something like $$c_0 + c_1v + c_2\ln(b + cv) = y$$

Comment: it doesn't make much sense the limit of integration on the LHS, as you are integrating w.r.t. $v$.

Comment: why it doesn't make sense? can you explain please.

Comment: Mr Chinny can you please give the full solution here.

Comment: @Husnain Are you sure its $\int_0^h dy$? Feels like the question should be $\int_0^y dy$.

Comment: Oh yes sir I have made a mistake while writing it.sorry. actually it is dh instead of dy.

Answer (score 1):

RHS: $$\int_o^h dy= y(h)-y(0)$$

LHS: Let $u=g-kv/m$ or $v=\frac{m}{k} (g-u)$ and so $du=-\frac{k}{m}dv$ or $dv= -\frac{m}{k}du$. So

$$\int{vdv\over g-kv/ m}=\int {vdv \over u}=  \frac{m^2}{k^2}\int  {(g-u) \over u}du=\frac{m^2}{k^2}\int  \left({g\over u }-1\right) du= \frac{m^2}{k^2} \left( g \ln u  - u \right) $$

Then $$\begin{align}\int_0^v {vdv\over g-kv/ m} &= \frac{m^2}{k^2} \left( g \ln u  - u \right) |_{g}^{\frac{m}{k} (g-u)} \\ 
&= \frac{m^2}{k^2} \left( g \ln (\frac{m}{k} (g-u))  - \frac{m}{k} (g-u) \right) - \frac{m^2}{k^2} \left( g \ln g  - g \right) \\
\end{align}$$

Now $g-u=g-(g-kv/m)=kv/m$. So,

$$\begin{align}& \ \ \frac{m^2}{k^2} \left( g \ln (\frac{m}{k} (kv/m))  - \frac{m}{k} (kv/m) \right) - \frac{m^2}{k^2} \left( g \ln g  - g \right) \\ 
&= \frac{m^2}{k^2} \left( g \ln (v)  - v \right) - \frac{m^2}{k^2} \left( g \ln g  - g \right) \\
&= \frac{m^2g}{k^2} \left( \ln (v)  - v/g \right) - \frac{m^2g}{k^2} \left( \ln g  - 1 \right) \\
&= \frac{m^2g}{k^2} \ln (v/g)  - \frac{m^2}{k^2} v/g  + \frac{m^2g}{k^2}\\
\end{align}$$

So we get that

$$ \frac{m^2g}{k^2} \ln (v/g) - \frac{m^2}{k^2} v/g  + \frac{m^2g}{k^2}=y(h)-y(0)$$